# Which libraries are needed for Firebase Admin SDK (Java)?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm trying to do Firebase Admin SDK app (with Java). I have included all the code that is provided on [Firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), have downloaded firebase-admin library, but the problem is that I'm always missing some other library too.

I've spent my all day so far just downloading libraries. I try to compile my code, and get an error that I'm missing a library, when I download it, I'm missing the next one, and so on.

I mean, shouldn't there be some list of libraries that you need to have in for Firebase Admin SDK app? Are we really expected to download libraries just one by one all day long? There is no such list in [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), they've just provied dependency for firebase-admin library, and I'm missing a BUNCH of others.

[image]

So in beginning I've had just firebase-admin-4.0.3 library, and I had to download the rest of these that are on the External libraries list, all one by one, and not knowing its Maven dependency at first.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved. The problem was that I was using any kind of dependency manager like Maven or Gradle. I mean I was using Maven but I in another project just to download dependencies and then manually include them in project(stupid).